# Flutter carouse_slider image always refresh make app crash

Tags: flutter

I have problem when listing multi images from api to carousel_slider. 
It always crash and show no error.

I have compare to my old app, it works as normal, but another one always crash.

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => HomeProvider(),
      child: Consumer<HomeProvider>(builder: (bContext, homeProderAction, _) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      key: refreshKey,
      onRefresh: () async {
        refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

        homeProderAction.setHomeData(homeData: fetchHomeData());
        return null;
      },
      child: FutureBuilder<HomeModel>(
        future: _homeData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('hello world');
          // if (_source.keys.toList()[0] == ConnectivityResult.wifi ||
          //     _source.keys.toList()[0] == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
            if (snapshot.hasData &&
                snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // return Container(
              //   child: ListView.builder(
              //       itemCount: 2 + snapshot.data.categories.length,
              //       shrinkWrap: true,
              //       addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              //       itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
              //         //Developer sum array of banner and course together
              //         //That's why list index 0 for homepage banner
              //         //And other for other ...
              //         if (ind == 0) {
                        return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                            viewportFraction: 1.0,
                            height: 100,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.courses.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
                              return Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                color: Colors.pink,
```

Comment: it is always better to add code which producing error. also add which version you are using of carousel_slider package.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I already add code in answer.

Comment: you should add it in question not as answer.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya ok

Comment: did you find the way to fix this?